# select sql query to merge results

Tags: sql

I have a table `old_data` and a table `new_data`. I want to write a select statement that gives me

1. Rows in old_data stay there
2. New rows in new_data get added to old_data
3. unique key is `id` so rows with `id` in `new_data` should update existing ones in `old_data`

I need to write  a select statement that would give me old_data updated with new data and new data added to it.

Example:

Table a:

```
id         count

1             2
2            19
3             4
```

Table b:

```
id         count

2            22
5             7
```

I need a SELECT statement that gives me

```
id         count

1             2
2            22
3             4
5             7
```

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using. `MERGE` serves this purpose

Comment: I don't want to use db specific construct. Something like join is what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your desired results:

```
        SELECT
             *
        FROM
             [TableB] AS B
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             *
        FROM
             [TableA] AS A
        WHERE
             A.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM [TableB])
```

Comment: Oh,no no. It's not max thing .Just the updated data from new table for a given id

Comment: @gags OK, Changed the answer, see this one.

Comment: This query will give me everything from Table B that was not in Table A.Looking at the example, it will never update row 2 with count value 22 instead of 19

Comment: @gags, you should have tried to run this code before you commented. you are not right.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work pretty neatly with COALESCE:

```
SELECT a.id, COALESCE(b.count, a.count)
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN b
ON a.id = b.id
```

Note - if your RDBMS does not contain COALESCE, you can write out the function using CASE as follows:

```
SELECT a.id,
CASE WHEN b.count IS NULL THEN a.count
ELSE b.count END AS count
FROM ...
```

You can write a FULL OUTER JOIN as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a.id = b.id
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM b
LEFT a
ON b.id = a.id
```

Comment: It should be `full outer join`

Comment: But it is not supported in `Mysql` OP wants the code to work in all sql dialect

Comment: Now it is fine. `COALESCE` is a ANSI SQL function it works across all `RDBMS` no need to use `CASE`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UPSERT to update old data and add new data in Old_data table and select all rows from Old_data. Check following and let me know what you think about this query

```
UPDATE [old_data]
SET [count] = B.[count]
FROM [old_data] AS A
INNER JOIN [new_Data] AS B
ON A.[id] = B.[id]

INSERT INTO [old_data]
           ([id]
           ,[count])
SELECT A.[id]
     ,A.[count]
FROM [new_Data] AS A
LEFT JOIN [old_data] AS B 
ON A.[id] = B.[id]     
WHERE B.[id] IS NULL

SELECT *
FROM [old_data]
```